# Where can i find the JS code in the Tailwind Components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Hi I am using Tailwind Components and is looking very good, but the buttons are not working (the buttons on the navbar when you resize), I didn't put the JavaScript because I did not find it.

https://tailwindui.com/components

I am using this one

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/cfs78mm0cozfwql/Screenshot%202020-06-25%2016.52.59.png?dl=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The buttons in the **tailwind components** are **skeleton** buttons. Tailwind only provides css not the js (action) part of it. You will have to create your own javascript code for that.